# How to receive a bounty from "Community"?

Tags: discussion, bounties, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

I was checking some bounties to see and realized that one of my answers was present on a newly bountied question.

This one to be specific: [500 window is not defined nuxt3 and composition api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74749323/8816585)

I forgot who was there initially but soon realized that [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17023430/sadeq-shahmoradi) recently got suspended.
So I'm not sure who or what happened there but the current bounty states

> Community `Bot` is looking for an answer from a reputable source.

How am I supposed to receive a bounty from a bot?

I know I can get half of it thanks to some votes but is there a way to get the integrality of it?

---

PS: In the end, not having it will gift me some Winterbash hat so I don't really mind not receiving it but I'm still quite curious.

Comment: See the section under "Otherwise, either all or half of the bounty will be awarded to the highest-scored answer among those which meet all of the following:"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Community owns things that would otherwise be unowned. So if a user starts a bounty and then deletes their account, Community steps in and owns the bounty.

It's true that Community won't manually award the bounty but then the user who deleted their account wouldn't be doing that either. So yes, half the bounty is all you can get here.

Comment: Yes, but user ["user20746969"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74749323/timeline#history_6904ebf8-bf78-45ec-8930-deff4759f90a) placed the bounty, while Sadeq retains his name, so two accounts; perhaps (due to the duration) a sock placed a bounty; resulting in its deletion and ...

Comment: @Rob yeah, probably some multi-account stuff. He was quite "active" lately from what I saw. I can see that it's wasn't a legit activity so far.